# How to test current date condition in behat?

Tags: testing, symfony4, behat

I have feature that is based on current date, and the question is if it is good solution to write if condition in scenario.  Simple example: if tested date is equal to current then other field is equal to 0 else equal 10. Meybe there are libraries to mock current date time in symfony 4.

Comment: Please be more specific because it is not very clear what you are trying to solve and add what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a step like:

```
Then I should see sysdate with format "Y-m-d" in the "example" field
```

Then for your context:

```
public function iShouldSeeSysdateWithFormatInTheField(string $format, string $key)
{
    $field = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findField($key);
    $value = (new DateTime())->format($format);

    if (is_null($field->getValue())) {
        assertEmpty($value);
    }

    if($value != $field->getValue()) {
        throw new Exception('date does not match');
    }
}
```